i want to echo error message when i didnt get the GET Method from my form and echo the form if i get
In this page I get id through the [$_GET[$id].
So I want to show the form if the ID in my database in present
and echo the error message when the id didn't get.
In this case when I didnt get the code the form is shown with error inside every form that they didnt find the record in database with this id
please look to these images:
this image when they find the id in the database:
enter image description here
this image when they didnt find the id in the database:
enter image description here
This is my code:
<?php
$title = "Edit";
require_once 'includes/header.php';
require_once 'db/config.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = $crud->getSingleAttendee($id);

if (!isset($id)) {
    echo "there are error";
} else {
    ?>
    <h1 class="text-center">Edit Attendee</h1>
    <form method='POST' action='success.php'>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="firstname" class="form-label">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<?php echo $result['firstname']?>" id="firstname" name="firstname">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="secondname" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<?php echo $result['lastname']?>" id="secondname" name="secondname" ></input>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="dob" class="form-label">Date Of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<?php echo $result['dateofbirth']?>" id="dob" name="dob"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="speciality" class="form-label">Speciality</label>
           
              
            <select class="form-control" id="speciality" name="speciality">
                <option selected>Choose Speciality</option>
            <!-- Get The Specialities Values and Name from data base -->
                
                <option value=<?php echo $result['speciality_id'] ?>><?php echo $result['selected'] ?></option>
                
            </select>
                
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" value= "<?php echo $result['emailaddress']?>" class="form-control"  id="email" name="email">
            <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="phone" class="form-label">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" value= "<?php echo $result['phone']?>" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
            <div id="phoneHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your number with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit"> Submit </button>
                
        </div>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<?php require_once 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
 

All I need to show error message with echo and not show the all form.

in shortest terms you should check if the id GET parameter is set before using it to fetch the corresponding row in the db. so try just moving the if condition on top as your very first statement like if( !isset($_GET['id']) ){  echo 'error'; exit; } else { //your logic fetching the db row and filling the html template } ... but it would still be hacky.. because you should actually handle errors in general

!isset($id) will always be false if you supply an id, whether or not it matches anything in your database.  Perhaps you need if (!$result) { instead?

This question is similar to: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PHP 7.4. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@shingo this is not similar to question u suggested and didnt help me

"All I need to show error message with echo and not show the all form." - what keeps you from doing exaclty that?

The warnings you get are triggered because when the id isn't present in the DB, $result is a boolean. Then when you use this variable in the code like following:
<input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<?php echo $result['firstname']?>" id="firstname" name="firstname">

the PHP part handles $result like an array, which is the case if the id could be found, but now it's a boolean. To fix this warning just use the null coalescing operator, see next:
<input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<?php echo $result['firstname'] ?? '' ?>" id="firstname" name="firstname">

To show a single error message you could add something like following before the form:
<?php if (!is_array($result)) { ?>
    <div>The id couldn't be found.</div>
<?php } ?>

